# How do I run multiple python files from another python file?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have three python files: `python1.py`, `python2.py`, `python3.py`. I wish to run all these three simultaneously from another file: `python0.py`. I wish that when `python0.py` is executed, the other 3 files should start running/executing simultaneously. I am a beginner in programming, it would be really great if someone could help me out.

I tried two methods but they weren't exactly helpful. In my first attempt I tried:

```py
import os

os.startfile("python1.py")
os.startfile("python2.py")
os.startfile("python3.py")
```

The problem here was than though these files would open, they would not begin execution on their own. In my second attempt I tried:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["python", "python1.py"])
subprocess.run(["python", "python2.py"])
subprocess.run(["python", "python3.py"])
```

The problem here was that though the files would begin execution, this would not be simultaneous. `python1.py` would begin execution but the others would not.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you need to use multithreading.
[Here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) is a solid tutorial.

You'll want to ensure that your code in each of your other files is contained in a function that can be imported.

### python1.py

```
def func1():
    do_stuff()
    do_more_things()
```

(Same for each of the other files)

### main.py

```py
import threading

from python1 import func1
from python2 import func2
from python3 import func3


thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func2)
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=func3)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this article](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) to run some files at once.

But for a quick guide you should create some files with one class in every file (always clean code) and then import them in the main python file.

```
from pythonFile0 import ClassaName...
```

After that you should use these packages in your main python file logging and threading to test the logs and make thread functions.
But main methods are in this line:

```
threading.Thread(target=ClassName.func().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of such problems can be solved with multiprocessing or multithreading by importing the functions you want to execute concurrently in the main file as suggested in another answer.

However, if you really need to run multiple Python "files" at the same time, you can use the `threading` module to call multiple `subprocess.run` concurrently.

for instance, lets say that `python1.py` (resp. `python2.py` and `python3.py`) is:

```py
from time import sleep


def func1():
    sleep(1.0)
    print("Done 1")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1()
```

It sleeps for one second and then prints something to `stdout`.

Your second attempt (non-concurrent) would look like this (`python0.py`):

```py
def main():
    d1 = subprocess.run(["python", "python1.py"], capture_output=True)
    d2 = subprocess.run(["python", "python2.py"], capture_output=True)
    d3 = subprocess.run(["python", "python3.py"], capture_output=True)

    print(d1.stdout)
    print(d2.stdout)
    print(d3.stdout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Since the execution is non-concurrent, this script would wait for a total of 3 seconds before completion.

Here is a concurrent version using the `concurrent.futures` module, (with is IMO simpler to use than the `threading` module for simple use-cases):

```py
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        r1 = pool.submit(
            lambda: subprocess.run(["python", "python1.py"], capture_output=True)
        )
        r2 = pool.submit(
            lambda: subprocess.run(["python", "python2.py"], capture_output=True)
        )
        r3 = pool.submit(
            lambda: subprocess.run(["python", "python3.py"], capture_output=True)
        )

        d1, d2, d3 = r1.result(), r2.result(), r3.result()

    print(d1.stdout)
    print(d2.stdout)
    print(d3.stdout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This version will only wait for 1 seconds before completing since the three files are run concurrently.

However, as I previously said, what you likely want is to execute multiple functions from different files (called modules) concurrently rather than executing "files" concurrently:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from python1 import func1
from python2 import func2
from python3 import func3


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        pool.submit(func1)
        pool.submit(func2)
        pool.submit(func3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```